# Creating 2 sets of .Net C# plugins for 2 diffferent external applications which have the same API except namespace

Tags: c#, .net, plugins, namespaces

I need to implement 2 set of plugin libraries with exactly the same code for 2 different external applications (I have no control of the external applications). Both applications expose .net classes with exactly the same API in different namespaces.

MyLibrary1 references VendorLibrary1
MyLibrary2 references VendorLibrary2

Both VendorLibrary1 and VendorLibrary2 expose SomeClass (class has the same name) with exactly the same methods.

How can I avoid the need to maintain 2 sets of identical source files (project files, references, cs files etc) which only differ in the using statements and references?

I already have 3 solution ideas which I consider too complicated so I am looking for something simpler/more elegant way of achieving this.

**Solution 1**
Somehow create wrappers around the vendor libraries which allows switching the library using DI or some other means.  The vendor libraries expose 100+ classes and most of them I am using so this is a considerable work and wrapping everything and using wrapped types in method signatures can quickly make this very complicated.

**Solution 2**
Use #if compiled defines in the using statements. Eg.

```
    #if VENDOR1
    using Vendor1NameSpace;
    #else
    using Vendor2NameSpace;
    #endif
```

Put all classes in one shared project and create 2 libraries, one library defines VENDOR1 and references VendorLibrary1 and the other defines VENDOR2 and references VendorLibrary2

I would need to create 2 sets of of all of my libraries, one for VENDOR1, one for VENDOR2

I think from this point on I need to maintain the using statements manually, can not rely on Resharper.

**Solution 3**
Implement the library against VendorLibrary1 and use a script which duplicates the solution. While duplicating the solution project references and namespaces in using statements are changed from VendorLibrary1 to VendorLibrary2, Vendor1NameSpace to Vendor2NameSpace etc.

Comment: You could make one real set of Classes, and those two in those other namespaces would just be "proxies".

Comment: @Christopher wouldn't that get very complicated? I would need to create a set of classes with class hierarchy. Is there a tool to create the proxy? Or do I need to manually code them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a simple code generator which implements solution 3. Code is developed against Vendor1 libraries and the code generator duplicates the library (project files with new name and source files) for Vendor2. It replaces referenced dlls in the project file and replaces namespaces in the source files. Works well.